# PDF.js error missing l10n which has be included

Tags: pdf.js

I'm trying to embed PDF.js into my web. 
Everything else is fine but when I run the page to display a pdf file it throw an error

**Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: mozL10n is not defined at webViewerInitialized**

I have checked my scripts and yeah I have included it:

Thank you for any help.

This is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/web/viewer.css') }}"/>

        <script language="javascript">
            var config = { 
                imageResourcesPath : "{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/images/') }}",
                workerSrc : "{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/build/pdf.worker.js') }}",
                pdfFile : "{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/build/hw.pdf') }}"
            };
        </script>

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/build/pdf.worker.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/web/l10n.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/build/pdf.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/web/debugger.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/leepadmin/web/viewer.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I have downloaded the Stable version. The viewer.js file in Stable version is missed the **mozL10n** variable.

So I go ahead and tried to find it in Beta version. And lucky I found it in Beta version.

It is fine now.